# Bot: Change permission to talk in a channel in 20s, creating a countdown and deleting these messages in the process

Tags: node.js, discord.js

For a Discord bot:

I want to run the command and get the message deleted.

After that, the bot sends a message that says the amount of seconds left (20) and then create an interval that each second will edit that message (A countdown basically: 20 second(s) left, 19 seco... 18 se...)

Once the 20 seconds timer ends, stop the countdown, delete that message and overwrite the permission.

> What actually happens is that my message gets deleted and my bot sends the initial message, but it won't get edited, won't get deleted and the permission won't be overwritten.

This is what I've tried (I have this command in a .js file):

```
module.exports = {
  name: "scycle",
  execute(client, message, args) {
    message.delete();
    var left = 20;
    var msgId = "nope";
    message.channel.send(left + " second(s) left").then(sent => {
      var getId = sent.id;
      msgId = getId.toString();
    });
    setInterval(function() {
      left--;
      message.guild.channels
        .get("726313177066766377")
        .fetchMessage(msgId)
        .edit(left + " second(s) left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      let player = message.guild.roles.get("726355606440771646");
      const channel = client.channels.get("id", "726313177066766377");
      channel.overwritePermissions(player, { SEND_MESSAGES: true });
      clearInterval();
      channel.fetchMessage(msgId).then(msg => msg.delete());
    }, 20000);
  }
};
```

Comment: That would be API spam which is against TOS, you should probably just send a gif that counts down from 20.

Comment: Oh thx, but what's exactly API spam? Can you explain me o give me link about a documentation?

Comment: API spam is just a concept not a feature to document. it's just combining the words API and spam, so basically overly simplified: repeated unnecessary actions like editing a message over and over in seconds or editing a role color every other second. If you are interested in the actual TOS just go to the offical page: https://discord.com/developers/docs/legal, API spam is covered in 2.7 and possibly some other sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I commented editing the message every second is not permitted, so you can either:

Just send the 20 second message, don't do anything else, a timer really isn't that necessary

or two: send a gif that counts down from 20

Either option would reduce a lot of your code and both could be altered from:

```js
message.delete();
message.channel.send("20 seconds left");

setTimeout(function () {
    let player = message.guild.roles.get("726355606440771646");
    const channel = client.channels.get("726313177066766377");
    channel.overwritePermissions(player, { SEND_MESSAGES: true });
}, 20000);
```

If you wanted to add the timer gif:

```js
async execute(client, message, args) {
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send("20 seconds left");

    //get reference to MessageAttachment class before
    const attachment = new MessageAttachment("https://i.makeagif.com/media/1-22-2017/GMpiJU.gif");
    const timer = await message.channel.send(attachment);

    setTimeout(function () {
        let player = message.guild.roles.get("726355606440771646");
        const channel = client.channels.get("726313177066766377");
        channel.overwritePermissions(player, { SEND_MESSAGES: true });
        timer.delete();
    }, 20000);
}
```

Comment: Realized that my whole code won't work, but it seems correct, thx